# Как изменить цвет текста в JMenuBar в Java?

Tags: java, swing

Не могу изменить цвет текста в JMenuBar. SetForeground не работает. Что делать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я решил проблему и хочу поделиться решением, может кому-то пригодится...
Если вы хотите изменить цвет текста, то его нужно изменять отдельно для каждого JMenu и JMenuItem.